# How to take output of function and use as input of another function python?

Tags: python, mysql

More specifically my function grabs all the domains in a my database table and returns them. I want to know how to input these domains into another function that will run the Kali Linux tool URLcrazy for each of the domains in that table.

For example my function that outputs these:

google.com
yahoo.com
**Here is the function:**

```
def grab_domains():
    try:
        db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",
                         user="root", passwd="root",
                         db="typosquat")
except ConnectionAbortedError as e:
    print(e, "\n")

temp = ""
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name From domains')
for rows in cursor.fetchall():
    for entries in rows:
        temp += entries
        domains = entries[0:]
        print(domains)

return temp
```

**Here is the output:**

google.com
yahoo.com

How do I write another function that will run the script URLcrazy on each of these domains? Assuming all scripts are in same file location.

This is all I have I cant figure out how to run it for each domain, only know how to for a single output.

```
def run_urlcrazy():
    np = os.system("urlcrazy " + grab_domains())
    print(np)
    return np
```

**How to I get this function to run URLcrazy for each domain?^^**

This is my first post ever on stack overflow let me know what I can do to improve it and help me with question if possible! Thanks

Comment: to put it simply, why dont you write the output from the first function to a file and read the file from your second script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a loop:

```
def run_urlcrazy():
    ret_vals = []
    for domain in grab_domains():
        np = os.system("urlcrazy " + domain)
        ret_vals.append(np)
    return ret_vals
```

I recommend a `for` loop because it can efficiently iterate over whatever your function returns.

---

You'll need to make a minor modification to your `grab_domains()` function as well:

```
temp = []
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT name From domains')
for rows in cursor.fetchall():
    for entries in rows:
        domains = entries[0:]
        temp.extend(domains)

return temp
```

Now, your function returns a list of domains. You can iterate over this.

Comment: `grab_domains()` is returning just a single `domain` right?

Comment: @pyjg I've proposed a modification. It seems OP is concatenating it in a string.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, was concatenating with string. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you, and glad I could help. :)